# Change point labels on plot created by plotTangentSpace in "geomorph" package

Tags: arrays, r, graph, plot, pca

Here is a classical example found on the help page for `plotTangentSpace` in package `geomorph`. I just add two lines: the construction of the vector `Myname` and the following line that name one dimension of the array `Y.gpa$coords` according to `Myname`.

```
library (geomorph)
data(plethodon)
Y.gpa<-gpagen(plethodon$land)    #GPA-alignment
ref<-mshape(Y.gpa$coords)
Myname = 41:80
dimnames(Y.gpa$coords)=list(NULL, NULL, Myname)
plotTangentSpace(Y.gpa$coords, label=T)
```

As you can see, on the plot created by `plotTangentSpace` the points are labeled 1:40 rather than 41:80 as I aimed to do by renaming `Y.gpa$coords`. I'd like to label the points according to  `Myname`. For this example my name is just a vector of numbers but I'd like it to works for character type also. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the code for `plotTangentSpace` (just type it in the R console), you first find the 'argument list':

```
function (A, axis1 = 1, axis2 = 2, warpgrids = TRUE, label = FALSE)
```

As you see you can turn labels 'on' or 'off' (`label = TRUE` or `FALSE`), but there is no argument for setting the actual value of the labels. Further down you find the code for the default, hard-coded labels (`seq(1, n)`) in two places:

```
    if (label == T) {
        text(pcdata[, axis1], pcdata[, axis2], seq(1, n), 
            adj = c(-0.7, -0.7))
```

...where `pcdata`, `axis1`, and `n` are defined in the beginning of the function.

Thus, if you want to set the value of the labels, it seems that you need to rewrite the function slightly. One possibility is to add a `labels` argument to the `arglist`:
`function (A, axis1 = 1, axis2 = 2, warpgrids = TRUE, label = FALSE, labels = NULL)`

...and change the arguments in both `text` calls:

```
  text(pcdata[, axis1], pcdata[, axis2], labels, 
       adj = c(-0.7, -0.7))
```

You also need to access the `tps` function in the `geomorph` namespace. This can be achived by adding `geomorph:::` before both instances of `tps`:

```
  geomorph:::tps(ref, shape.min, 20)
  geomorph:::tps(ref, shape.max, 20)
```

Then assign the updated function to a new function name:

`plotTangentSpace2 <- function (A, axis1 = 1, axis2 = 2, warpgrids = TRUE, label = FALSE, labels = NULL){

lots-of-stuff

      text(pcdata[, axis1], pcdata[, axis2], labels, 
           adj = c(-0.7, -0.7)) # in both places

more-stuff

      geomorph:::tps(ref, shape.min, 20)

      geomorph:::tps(ref, shape.max, 20)

}`

Plot with the updated function, using 'Myname' as labels:
`plotTangentSpace2(Y.gpa$coords, label = TRUE, labels = Myname)`
[image]